# Add DataAugmentation and rescaling in CNN with Keras sequential API

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

How do you add data augmentation and rescaling layer in a Convolution Network in Keras?

This is how I have defined it with functional API:

```
image_size = (32,32)
data_augmentation = keras.Sequential(
  [
    layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomFlip(),
    layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomRotation(0.25),
    layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomZoom(0.25),
  ]
)

inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=image_size + (3, ), name='input')
data_aug = data_augmentation(inputs)
rescaling = tf.keras.layers.Rescaling(1. / 255)(data_aug)
conv_1 = layers.Conv2D(
    32, 3, padding='valid', name='conv_1')(rescaling)
```

Without the data_augmentation and rescaling, the input shape is just defined in the first convolution layer:

```
model_seq = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model_seq.add(layers.Conv2D(
    32, 3, padding='valid', input_shape = image_size + (3, ), name='conv_1'))
```

But i'm not sure what should I have to do. Just add the data augmentation and rescaling prior to convolution without an input layer? Do I add an input layer and remove shape definition in the first convolution?

Comment: I am not sure if you can apply the previous layers in the context of data augmentation, since they applied changes will erase the original image. Normally, you apply data augmentation on the offline data before training or maybe inside the generator by applying these different transformation and then train your model on them.

Comment: @user2586955, in this code, on each epoch the input dataset CHANGES (random flip, rotation and zoom). Isn't it a good practice to force your model to make a better generalization instead 'memorizing' samples (some kind of overfit)?